# lookbehind in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to use regex to match and replace anything between my file name and closing parentheses.

I wrote a regex:

```
/(?<=imagecheck.php)[^)]*/
```

That works in php, but not in Javascript.

...How would I do in JS?

example:

```
 input string example 1: url(127.0.0.1/imagecheck.php)
 input string example 2: url(127.0.0.1/imagecheck.php?boost=9881732213826123918238)
 outcome string example: url(127.0.0.1/imagecheck.php?reload=oh_yes_plx&boost=123810982346023984723948723023423)
```

Comment: Have you tried Google? http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind

Comment: I think that you don't need regex, but I need to understand exactly what you want. Can you post some examples of what are you trying to do?

Comment: You must be kidding arxanas, that's going to explode my head for sure.

Comment: @WaleedKhan no we use bing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look-behind is not supported in Javascript. You can use capturing group to capture the text after `"imagecheck.php"` instead:

```
.match(/imagecheck.php([^)]*)/)
```

The result will be in index 1 of the returned array (if there is a match).

This is an example of removing whatever after `"imagecheck.php"`

```
.replace(/(imagecheck.php)[^)]*/, "$1")
```

Comment: @nhahtdh: I think the question has always said so ;) Always check before being snarky!

Comment: @Anonymous: What do you want to replace?

Comment: @Anonymous: You are not clear on what you want to replace it with. I can just dump an example, but it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I'm not sure it's urgent that we know what the replacement is. The regular expression contains no match groups, so it's fair to assume that it's just some constant string that we as answerers don't care about.

Comment: I want to replace it with any input I like, for example a query string such as ?reload=yes&boost=123 it should replace an old query string, but should also match an empty space if the file has none.

Comment: @Anonymous: My regex, or jfriend00's regex should work. Your original regex is correct, just need to rewrite to remove the look-behind.

Comment: @Matchu: There are different things that you can do with the match (throw away and replace with new, use the match and put something before/after), or sometimes it is a requirement that regex is not appropriate. It is important to know what is replaced to some degree.

Comment: Well, it works :-) So far it's the most compact and neat solution, so I'm gonna stick with it :) THanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without look-behind in javascript, you can replace everything between your filename and the closing paren like this:

```
str = str.replace(/imagecheck.php\([^)]*\)/, "imagecheck.php(whatever)");
```

or, you can use capture groups and numbered references to avoid repeating the initial pattern:

```
str = str.replace(/(imagecheck.php)\([^)]*\)/, "$1(whatever)");
```

Comment: …but this answer is better than my XRegExp answer for being faster, dependency-free, and all-around cleaner :)

Comment: @Anonymous: if you're looking to be DRY, you could always create the regexp using the form `new RegExp(prefix + "[^)]*")` and then run `str.replace(pattern, prefix + "{whatever suffix}")`

Answer (score 1):

XRegExp doesn't support lookbehind directly. For that, you'd need to use the addon script previously linked to by @arxanas: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind. Also, XRegExp doesn't use forward-slash delimiters within its pattern strings.

Comment: This was meant as a comment in reply to @Matchu. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Though Javascript doesn't natively support lookbehind in regular expressions, we *could* pull in [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), a more powerful Javascript regex engine.

```
var pattern = XRegExp('/(?<=imagecheck.php)[^)]*/', 'g'); // g is the global flag
XRegExp.replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```