# Regexp (?<=string) is giving invalid group error?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match a string like `<tag>something</tag>` and I want the result to return only `something` without the tags.

i tried using:

```
string.match(/(?<=<tag>).*?(?=<\/tag>)/g);
```

but its giving an error:

`SyntaxError:Invalid regular expression: /(?<=<tag>).*?(?=<\/tag>)/: Invalid group`;

why is it not working?

Comment: Related: [lookbehind in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597718/lookbehind-in-javascript)

Comment: `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>`

from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Jan i'm not trying to parse html, i just need to convert string which has tags like structure

Comment: @razzak is that a structure eerily similar to XML but not really XML  or SGML? What it _is_, then?

Comment: @Jan it looks like XML but doesn't have a valid structure so i can't parse it with XML parsers

Comment: @razzak is that a standard format? If yes, please point me to it. If not, I recommend using a standard format instead. Say, XML or JSON.

Comment: @Jan i can't change the format because it's done on the server side, i wish i could change it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will like this

```
/(?:<(tag)>)((?:.(?!<\/\1>))+.)(?:<\/\1>)/g
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[image: visualize the match, luke!]

This is handy because the `\1` [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) matches tag *pairs*

---

Use it on text like this

```
var re  = /(?:<(tag)>)((?:.(?!<\/\1>))+.)(?:<\/\1>)/g,
    str = "this is <tag>some text</tag> and it does <tag>matching</tag>",
    match;

while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(match[1], match[2]);
};
```

Output

```
tag some text
tag matching
```

---

**Bonus Soda!** You can simply modify `(tag)` to be `(tag|bonus|soda)` to have it work on this string

```
<tag>yay</tag> and there's even <bonus>sodas</bonus> in <soda>cans</soda>
```

---

**Beware** If you nest tags, you would have to apply this regexp recursively.

Comment: nice picture. Did you make it? Please point to the tool you have used.

Comment: thank you very much naomik it works :), great explanation and very nice picture. i was hoping i won't need to use loop but i think it's the only way to do it.

Comment: @razzak, the only way to multiple captures with a `//g` regex is to use the loop :)

Comment: @JanDvorak, [debuggex](http://debuggex.com)

Comment: @JanDvorak, I appreciate the edit, but the source is right there in the image url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a lookbehind, which JavaScript does not support. You'd have to change the pattern to something like this:

```
/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g
```

And then extract the appropriate group. For example:

```
/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g.exec('<tag>something</tag>')[1]; // something
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it includes the tags in the results

Comment: @razzak As I mentioned, you'd have to extract the group.

Comment: how can i make it work on multiple matches? like if i have '<tag>one</tag><tag>two</tag>' and i want to extract the values to an array

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: It would be possible to make this work on multiple matches by looping in some way (and always removing / not respecting / replacing an already checked part of the original string). However, the accepted answer is accepted rightfully so because it's simpler, cleaner and more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = /<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/.exec(myString,"g");
```

The text between the  is then in result[1].

Comment: how can i make it work on multiple matches? like if i have '<tag>one</tag><tag>two</tag>' and i want to extract the values to an array