# Get text between tags regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the text between the two tags which also handles multiple lines.I have managed to do it in PHP regex but i am stuck on the javascript one.

```
   <any_tag>random text
   dffdffdfdfdfdfdfdfd
   dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf
   </any_tag>
   I want to get the text between <any_tag> and </any_tag>
```

This is the regex for php
       https://regex101.com/r/tQ1bX7/2

Now i am trying to achieve to same in javascript

Comment: Oh you have? Try with `<any_tag>random  I want to get the text between <any_tag> and </any_tag>text </any_tag>`

Comment: Tag name is static? And is it well formed?

Comment: Use `/<any_tag>([\s\S]*)(?=<\/any_tag>)/` and grab captured group #1

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes its static

Comment: See this: https://regex101.com/r/tQ1bX7/4

Comment: check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320702/regexp-string-is-giving-invalid-group-error

Comment: @soldiershin why do you need regex for that? you can simply get using JavaScript's native function document.getElementsByTagName("any_tag")[0].innerHTML;

Comment: Check out [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF5lI8/2). Capture group 1 contains the match. JS doesn't have lookbehind assertions so you   'll have to resort to numbered capture groups anyway, therefore you can do away with the lookahed assertion as well. angle brackets do not need to be escaped in JS.

Comment: Try this: `/(?<=\<any_tag\>)(?:.*(\r?\n?.*)*)(?=\<\\/any_tag\>)/`

Comment: thanks @anubhava and collasper..i captured the first group which includes the first tag.So there isn't a way to capture the text without getting the start tag

Comment: @Proggear this doesnt work in javascript but works in php regex

Comment: @soldiershin: No as there is no lookbehind in JS

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Give try on following :

```
/[^(<any_tag>)](?:.*(\r?\n?).*)*(?=\<\/any_tag\>)/gi
```

Explination :

```
[^(<any_tag>)] match a single character not present in the list below
(<any_tag>) a single character in the list (<any_tg>) literally (case insensitive)
```